# Looking for a sensor recommendation

Tags: sensor, embedded, stepper-motor, proximity-sensor

I am using a stepper motor that is belt driving a 3-4inch diameter pulley.  The motor is quite small, only a NEMA11.  I am trying to find a sensor that will reliably home the motor.  I first tried a Hall effect sensor and switch and attached a small magnet to the pulley, but I am finding this is too unreliable for precise homing, and have a feeling this will get worse with temperature fluctuations.

I believe there are optical sensors that could detect a significant color change or something.  For instance, if I placed a black mark on a silver pulley, it would detect this change and know it had homed, but I just can't seem to find the right name or sensor for this.

Comment: Usually you home the axis, not the pulley... What happens if the belt slips?

Comment: An "optical rotary encoder" is a common way to keep track of the position of stepper motor.

Comment: Gus, what I have done is use an optical quadrature encoder and then tentatively tightened it down to the shaft with a screw. This is then run through a series of operations where the motor is spun at different speeds and the homing pulse as well as the A/B quadrature information is placed up on a real-time display. I can then gently slide the encoder around the shaft until things lined up right. Then the encoder was glued permanently and re-tested. This was for an infusion pump motor where lives were on the line in hospitals. It worked well.

Comment: Gus, what are your precision requirements? How much variation in the position of the outer diameter of your pulley can you tolerate, each time it homes? Is this in microns or mm, for example?

Comment: This isn't a CNC style problem.  There an unbelievably small load being placed on the system.  Just a stepper motor driving a very small light pulley at low speeds, usually stationary.

Comment: I should also probably say the motor technically will only use about 360deg of rotation.  It will be spinning something inside of the pulley, and will never need to spin more than 1 rotation in either direction.  @jonk Precision is definitely the goal.  I am microstepping in 1/256 increments with a 1.8degree stepper, so reliably getting back to within a few microsteps is the goal.

Comment: @Gus So, 25 arc-seconds per microstep? Or over 50k microsteps per full revolution? I used a 10k optical encoder for the infusion pump. You are going to need something like that, I fear. A painted stripe on a wheel isn't going to cut it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question as you posed it, that is to reliably find a position on the belt itself by the coloration of the belt I think you are looking for a reflective optical sensor: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/optical-sensors-reflective-analog-output/546

Many of these have analog outputs that can be digitized with a comparator circuit that is tuned your specific needs: the difference in reflected energy between the marked and unmarked sections of the belt, the distance to the belt from the sensor.  You can vary the intensity of the transmitter as well as adjust the comparator threshold to tune your circuit to work reliably for your setup. (I have used these many years ago to detect trains passing by on a track with a crude barcode encoding the ID).

Comment: Thanks gcr, I was starting to lean into trying one of these next.

Answer (score 1):

If your ability to draw a high contrast line has a transition larger than the angular resolution then you must choose a slot type optical detector.  This permits higher SNR of the output and great immunity to stray light and greater ability to make a sharp edge for slot interruption of light.

For these reasons, it has been the sensor of choice for Home sensors = Track 0" on Floppy disk drives, early stepper driven HDD's and any high precision CNC servo system.

This requires a flag to be attached to the rotor to pass thru the light beam from one side only for repeatability.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you've thought through your requirements.

If you have a 4" diameter pulley, and 200 step/rev stepper, and a 1/256 microstepper, your belt movement per microstep will be

(2 x 6.28) / (200 x 256),

or about .000245 in/microstep. Allowing "a few microsteps" (let's call it two) tolerance for the home position, you need a sensor which will detect a belt marker to .0005 inches. More or less. This ignores the fact that position accuracy from a microstepper is never as good as the ratio implies. In your case, you are in relatively good shape, since you've specified that the load is light. I'm not at all sure that low-cost commercial units are going to do that for you. At the very least, you'll need to make sure that your reflective marker has very smooth, sharp edges, with a roughness less than your desired step size. Here https://www3.panasonic.biz/ac/ae/service/tech_support/fasys/tech_guide/data/photoelectric_e.pdf is a Panasonic technical brochure which claims that one of its units is capable of 20 um resolution.

In your place I think I'd try for a pass-thru setup. Drill the smallest hole you can in the pulley just below the belt portion, then set up an illuminator/detector setup to detect the hole. Use a bare fiber optic to provide illumination, and you should be able to get very sharp edge detection due to the small fiber diameter. Of course, if you do something like that you'll need to use a toothed timing belt/pulley combination to prevent slippage of the belt.

If you want to use an out-of-the-box sensor, you'll need to do some experimentation on candidate sensors. You'll also need to evaluate the mechanical stability of whatever sensor setup you pick - .0005 inches is in the realm where you can get in trouble very easily.

Comment: Thanks for you comments.  Following GCR's advice I landed on the sensor that Tony was reccomending (one just like it).  I am going to try a very similar setup to the one you propose.  The pulley was already going to be driving a toothed belt.  So far my testing has indicated that my loads will be fine at 1/256 microstepping, I just need to find a homing mechanism I am comfortable with and I think you guys have helped me get there.